# Issue with method called several times at the same time

Tags: java, singleton

I have this method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/affaires",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
public ResponseEntity<Affaire> createAffaire(@RequestBody Affaire affaire, HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException {
  Long idMax = affaireRepository.getMaxId();
  affaire.setReferenceAffaire("AF_"+LocalDate.now().getYear()+" - "+idMax);
  Affaire result = affaireRepository.save(affaire);
```

My problem : In my database I have 2 affaires with same ReferenceAffaire.

So I guess that the method was called twice at exactly the same time and that at each time idMax was the same.
Is there a way to avoid this method to be called several times at exactly the same time ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `synchronized` tho the functions declaration. This prevents exactly what you want:  threads wanting to call this function at the same time are put in a queue and executed one after another

```
public synchronized ResponseEntity<Affaire> createAffaire(@RequestBody Affaire affaire, HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException {
```

see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) here.

Answer (score 1):

## Servlets are threaded

Servlets, by definition, are a threaded environment. Each request is handled on a thread, so many requests mean many threads. But even two requests (two threads) brings the risk of concurrency problems. So **every servlet programmer must write thread-safe code**.

> So I guess that the method was called twice at exactly the same time and that at each time idMax was the same.

Yes, entirely possible. And, if you are seeing repeated numbers being assigned, this indeed is the likely cause.

## `synchronized`

Any shared resource that is not built to be thread-safe must be protected. In your particular case that means the `affaireRepository.getMaxId()` method need protection. One way to do that is `synchronized`. But we’d have to know much more to make the best recommendation.

Anyone writing servlet code should be reading, studying, and re-reading the book by Brian Goetz et al., [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/127932).

> Is there a way to avoid this method to be called several times at exactly the same time ?

No.

In earlier versions of the Java Servlet specification, here was an option to tell the Servlet container to run a particular Servlet in single-thread mode. If that Servlet were the sole place `affaireRepository.getMaxId()` is being called, then single-thread mode would indeed prevent that method being called simultaneously. But this feature was removed in later versions of the spec. Being single-threaded kills the performance promised by Java Servlet technology. And there may have been other issues as well, I don’t recall.

Again, if you are writing any Servlet code that accesses non-thread-safe resources, then **you must learn about concurrency**, and study `synchronized`, `volatile`, the Java Memory Model, the Executor framework, avoiding `Timer`, JSR 236 Concurrency Utilities for Java EE, and other issues. Most of that, along with key concepts, is covered in that book mentioned above.

Concurrency and thread-safety is complicated, challenging to learn, and tricky to write properly. But it is certainly possible. Modern Java provides some of the best facilities in the industry for such work.

## UUID

As an alternative identifier for your records, consider using a [Universally Unique Identifier (UUID)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). Threading and concurrency would not be an issue with regard to generating ID values.

---

By the way, your code has other problems.

## Time Zone

Calling LocalDate.now() implicitly uses the JVM’s current default time zone. That default can change at any moment. So you could end up sequence numbers assigned out of order to a previous year, if the zone were changing around New Years Day.

Instead, always specify explicitly your desired time zone.

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```